# Adding and getting info from SQL DB using VS2013

Tags: c#, sql, .net, visual-studio

what i am trying to do is to create a page that afer getting some input from the user (name,surname) the user will click submit button and the system will check in the database connected with te page if a person with these credentials is already in teh database and then display it. 
I have already conected the database with the VS2013 and the DB table is showing all the time in the page , but i want it to display after clicking Submit.

Some of my Code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
            cnn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AdventureWorks2014ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            cnn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

            cmd.CommandText = "select * FROM [dbo].[users] WHERE FirstName= TextBox1";
            cmd.Connection = cnn;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, " users ");
            SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
            DataRow drow = ds.Tables["users"].NewRow();

            drow["FirstName"] = TextBox2.Text;
            drow["LastName"] = TextBox2.Text;

            ds.Tables["TableName "].Rows.Add(drow);
            da.Update(ds, " users ");
        }
        catch(Exception EX)
        {
            string A = "";
        }
    }

    protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AdventureWorks2014ConnectionString %>"
         SelectCommand="SELECT [FirstName], [LastName], [Gender] FROM [users]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
           AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" 
           DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" 
           GridLines="None">
           <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />

           <Columns>

              <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName"
                 HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="FirstName" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName"
                 HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="LastName" />

           </Columns>
           <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" 
              Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
           <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" 
              ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
           <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" 
              Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
           <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True"  
              ForeColor="White" />
           <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
           <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: OMG. Are you intentionally use SQLDataAdapter to update data in your DB? Why don't use standart sql UPDATE ?

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Comment: I would highly recommend using an orm to start with if you are new to using a back end database.  the .net framework has prebuilt projects that will create the connectors for you with entity framework.